# making an object follow a path libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am making a game that has objects that shoot other objects. I need the enemies to follow a path. The easiest way I can think of doing this is by having an array of coordinates and they move between them. But when I make a curve in the path, I don't want to have to put in 100 coordinates. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gdx AI that provides you with an API for that :

- https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/blob/master/gdx-ai/src/com/badlogic/gdx/ai/steer/behaviors/FollowPath.java

Also check the wiki :

- https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Steering-Behaviors

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java very well and never touched libgdx but IMHO i think you should use a pathfinder, in a quick google search i found that libgdx has a [pathfinder "Method"](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/gdx-ai/docs/com/badlogic/gdx/ai/pfa/PathFinder.html).

If you set a "hardcoded" path for your npc they wont be able to move around obstacles or other npc but if you set a walkable kind of tiles like "path" or "grass" or whatever and implements a pathfinder algorithm your npc gonna walk by themselves.

Depending on your needs you can use the prebuilt libgdx pathfinder algorithm or build your own from scratch.

Good luck mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need use a spline. A cubic spline is good for this. You can use it to  take a group of waypoints in space and create a curved path between all of the points.

The maths can look a bit heavy. I managed to find this site with java examples ( which is easier for me to understand than the actual maths :) ) 
http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic

You can also investigate hermite curves.